# Preserving Geometry of Shape file after merging edges using Networkx

Tags: qgis, python, networkx, stream

I have a stream network and I want it to convert in a graph like data structure having vertices with only degree 1 and 3. The degree of the vertex is the number of edges incident to that vertex. The current stream network also contains degree 2 vertices which are to be eliminated. The elimination is expected as the merging of adjacent edges of the vertex with degree 2 node as shown below. The label in the figure represents the stream vertex id and degree of the vertex (ID-Degree)

Input shapefile--Stream Network and Point layer

[image: Stream Network]

Expected Output:-

[image: Stream Network Output]

It can be seen from the above figure that initially the shapefile has stream segments as 60-> 61, 61->64, 64->65 and the output stream network has 60-> 65 as the stream segment with edges corresponding to degree two nodes are merged.

Below is my code using Networkx which reads a shapefile and eliminates the degree two nodes from the network.

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()

path='/home/swapnil/Desktop/code/Final_files'
G=nx.read_shp(path + '/Stream_Segment_Vect.shp' , geom_attrs =  True , strict = True) 
pos = {k: v for k,v in enumerate(G.nodes())}
X=nx.Graph() #Empty graph
X.add_nodes_from(pos.keys()) #Add nodes preserving coordinates
# print(pos.keys())
l=[set(x) for x in G.edges()] #To speed things up in case of large objects
edg=[tuple(k for k,v in pos.items() if v in sl) for sl in l] #Map the G.edges start and endpoints onto pos
# print(edg)
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(X,pos,node_size=100,node_color='r')
X.add_edges_from(edg)



remove = [node for node,degree in dict(X.degree()).items() if degree == 2]



# For each of those nodes
for node in remove:
    # We add an edge between neighbors (len == 2 so it is correct)
    # print(node)
    X.add_edge(*X.neighbors(node))
    # And delete the node
    X.remove_node(node)

X.remove_nodes_from(remove)

nx.draw_networkx_edges(X,pos)

# print(X.degree[1])

plt.show()
```

But this code creates a straight line between merged edges as shown below instead of preserving the geometry which stream network had.

[image: Networkx Output]

Doubts:-
1)Does networkx preserve shapefile geometry when imported to QGIS, irrespective of how the image output is displayed, if yes, how?

2)How can I import geometry attributes in QGIS of the image output of networkx?

Comment: One more time : **1)** you don't explain what's your 'point' layer is (since it doesn't seem to be your line layer vertices) **2)** Do u want a geographic table as result ? if you delete nodes _(vertices)_ you won't preserve geometry ... so do u intend to play with one or two tables ? **3)** don't u rather expect **a graph** showing connectivity between 3-degrees nodes ?

Comment: 1)Point layer is the set of points where the stream segments are broken i.e. are the connection between edges. 2) Yes, I want a geographic table as a result. The node/point layer is just for illustration purpose and the networkx itself identifies the nodes separately. 3)Yes, I expect a graph showing connectivity between nodes having only degree3 and degree 1.

Comment: I ask that because your line layer is showing more 'nodes' than your point layer ... are we ok with that ?

Comment: Yes, that's fine.

Comment: And ... a connectivity graph is something different than a geographic table .... are u ok with that ?

Comment: Yes , it should just have FROM  and TO  attributes in the table as well.